# How do I set up a stack by type, such as Range or Box?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline, vis-timeline

I am trying to create a graph using [`vis-timeline`](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline).

I would like to use `subgroup` or something similar to set up stacking for `Range` and `Box` of the same type and non-stacking for another type.

For example, assume the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07pUI.png)

Is it possible to achieve this with the latest `vis-timeline` library?
And how can I make it happen?

I tried to separate `subgroups` by type and set the `stackSubgroups` property, but I get the following display.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Mk9.png)